# Removing history entries for files and not being able to checkout folder

Tags: git, github, lithium

I downloaded the lithium library from it's git repo a while back, and was using that to build on my own application. I hadn't thought about the possible git issues as I didn't know much about git at the time (still don't really) - but I've now put this git repo onto GitHub as I will need to collaborate with some people; however the whole history of the commits for the lithium framework is in there, as would be expected.

Basically I have committed a load of stuff myself in developing the application, and it seems to be causing some issues. I didn't know if there was a way to remove the history of the lithium files (or from a particular date, i.e. when I started committing files) or something that I can do to resolve it. I don't really want to start my git repo again from scratch as there is quite a bit of history in it that is useful.

If anyone could suggest something that I might be able to do, either in removing the history from a date or exporting some of it...?

Because of this, I think it has stopped me being able to download the lithium folder when checking out the code - looking at the folder in Github, I just see a folder with a green arrow when I look at /libraries/lithium and no way to click on it or see why that is the case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Dan

Answer (score 2):

That green arrow you see points to a submodule, which lives there: https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium (`git submodule init && git submodule update`)

What I would do is to pick a fresh version of lithium itself and start using it. You'd have mostly modified files from the framework which is *your* application and can remain so. Keep your actual version somewhere, you'll always be able to check any modifications using a *diff* application like **Meld**, **KDiff**, …

I don't think it'd be that complex to start over, file by files with a proper diff tool.

Don't hesitate to join us on IRC: irc://irc.freenode.net/#li3 to ask anything you want about li3 and stuff.

Best of luck!

Comment: You can simplify submodule init and update with `git submodule update --init`

Comment: if he wants and can upgrade its code from the framework repository, it's a valid solution indeed.